# Hiding rows that have the symbol form of "x" in it

Tags: excel, rows, hidden, vba

I have part of a script in which I want to hide all rows containing the symbol "x" which is in font "wingdings" known as `ChrW(&HFB)`. The code below seems to throw up error 1004. However I do not know how to get around it? Any suggestions ?

```html
Set rng1 = ws.Range(Target, .Cells(.Rows.Count, Target.Column).End(xlUp))

'Identify next empty range in final sheet
sizey = rng1.Rows.Count
Drows = sizey + 6
        
Set rng2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(7, 2), ws2.Cells(Drows, 2))
rng2.Value = rng1.Value
      
For Each Cell In rng2
    If Cell.Value = ChrW(&HFB) Then
        .EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: It might help if you described what range you are trying to get, because from looking at the formula, it's hard to determine if you have it right or wrong.  Are you debugging using your Locals Window? To check and make sure the Ranges are what you expect?

Comment: In the first row, `Cells` and `Rows` have a leading period.  This means they must be within a With statement.  Perhaps showing the entire block of code would help.

Comment: I have just figured out why it was not working, there were some rows hidden and therefore was throwing up an error. I have now added a line to show all cells before the code gets to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show all hidden rows first.

```html
Sub Filter_Sheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim sizey As Long
    Dim Drows As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
              
    Set ws = Worksheets("Measurement Signal List - SPA")
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Measurement Info Sheet")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Filter Page")
   'Show hidden cells 
    ws2.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    
    If ActiveCell.Column > 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Please choose File name from Column 1")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
        MsgBox ("Please choose a file")
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    With ws
        Set Target = .Cells.Find(What:=ActiveCell.Value, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
        If Not Target Is Nothing Then
          Set rng1 = ws.Range(Target, .Cells(.Rows.Count, Target.Column).End(xlUp))
          'Identify next empty range in final sheet
            sizey = rng1.Rows.Count
            Drows = sizey + 6
            
          Set rng2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(7, 2), ws2.Cells(Drows, 2))
          rng2.Value = rng1.Value
                   
          For Each Cell In rng2
          If Cell.Value = ChrW(&HFB) Then
          Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
          End If
          If Cell.Value = ChrW(&HFC) Then
          Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(6, 232, 49)
          End If
          Next Cell
                                 
              Else
            MsgBox "File not found"
        End If
    End With
    
    Set rng3 = ws2.Range("A1")
    Application.Goto Reference:=rng3, Scroll:=True
    
End Sub
```